# Calculating the sum of input values by id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Help with calculate sum (total) of the entered values by using id's

but its not working out for me

i appreciate for help

```
<input type="number" id="do" name="i1">

  <input type="number" id="to" name="i2">

$("#do").keyup(function() {
  var tot = 0;
  $("#to").each(function() {
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot + ' usd');
});
```

Comment: An id value can only be used once per page.

Comment: Really are you sure?

Comment: Really are you sure?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If you have two `<input>` elements both with id "to", that's incorrect.

Comment: @dgknca that's true in the posted sample, but the code makes no sense unless the OP has multiple elements with id "to".  What would be the point of computing a total if there were only one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is almost ready. The problem is that you are not using the value of `$("#do")`:

```js
$("#do").keyup(function() {
  var tot = Number($(this).val());
  $("#to").each(function() {
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot + ' usd');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="do" name="i1">

  <input type="number" id="to" name="i2">

<span id="tot-qty"></span>
```

EDIT:

As suggested in the other answer, you can make it more general:

```js
$(".summe").keyup(function() {
  var tot = 0;
  $(".summe").each(function() {
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot + ' usd');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="do" class="summe" name="i1">

  <input type="number" id="to" class="summe" name="i2">

<span id="tot-qty"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML "id" attributes must be unique per DOM (only one element can have a given "id").  You won't receive an error if there are more than one of the same id on the DOM, but you will not get the desired behavior.

You might be able to achieve what you're trying to do by changing the `id` to a `class`, but I haven't tested.  Alternatively - you can also use jQuery's selectors as well (depending on your total markup).

Something like this:

```
var allInputElements = $(":input");
allInputElements.each(function(){ ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use classes for this case and also convert the value to integer make a new class and add that class to each element you wanted to sum . Because the each function you cant use with id because id represents a unique element.